# C program for how to reverse a number explanation needed

Tags: c, reverse

While searching for a C program on how to reverse a string, i came across the below program. I am already familiar with a program where we take the length of the string and then minus each character and find the reverse. But this a different program. So can someone please tell me how this code works? Help will be gratefully accepted.
compiler used is Borland Turbo c.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main() {
    char str[50];
    char rev[50];
    int i, j, n;
    clrscr();
    printf("enter the string to be reversed:");
    scanf("%s", &str);
    for (i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++) {
        n = i - 1;
    }
    for (j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++) {
        rev[j] = str[i];
        n--;
    }
    printf("the reverse of the string is:%s", rev);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: something is wrong here.

Comment: This is not an "explain my code" site. And that has several problems. Get a better one with explaination supplied.

Comment: The program doesn't work either. How did it work for you? The program simply writes `strlen(str)` NUL-terminators into `rev`.

Comment: And whats the purpose of `n`?

Comment: @CoolGuy No the code didnt work. But unless i know how it works, i'm not going to be able to execute it properly.

Comment: @Saneyar The loops in the posted code simply does the same thing as `int len = strlen(str); int i; for(i = 0; i < len; i++) rev[i] = '\0';`

Comment: @CoolGuy please refer to this- http://www.studytonight.com/c/reverse-a-string-program.php

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work as it is supposed to.Have you tried it ?

Consider this approach to reverse a string :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int reverse(char *Str);
void swap(char *x, char *y);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char Str[255];
    printf("enter the string to be reversed : ");
    scanf("%s", Str);
    reverse(Str);
    printf("the reverse of the string is : %s\n", Str);
}

int reverse(char *Str) {
    size_t len = strlen(Str);
    size_t n = len / 2;
    char *begin = Str;
    char *end = (Str + len) - 1;

    while (n > 0) {
        swap(begin, end);
        begin++;
        end--;
        n--;
    }
    return 0;
}

void swap(char *x, char *y) {
    char tmp;
    tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings are NUL-terminated meaning that it has `'\0'` at the end signifying the end of the string. The code you've posted currently has two issues:

1. This:

   ```
   scanf("%s", &str);
   ```

   should be

   ```
   scanf("%s", str);
   ```

   as `%s` expects a `char*`, not a `char(*)[50]`.
2. This:

   ```
   rev[j] = str[i];
   ```

   should be

   ```
   rev[j] = str[n];
   ```
3. `rev` should be NUL-terminated before printing. Add

   ```
   rev[j] = '\0';
   ```

   just before

   ```
   printf("the reverse of the string is:%s", rev);
   ```

   to avoid Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I will correct the above mentioned mistakes and try to execute the code.